# Annotating interrupt handlers and registers in Coverity-scan

Tags: embedded, static-analysis, coverity

I am in the process of setting up Coverity-Scan in an embedded systems project (C99 language). The codebase makes use of interrupts and system peripheral registers (like most embedded software). I don't know if it is ignoring code paths which are the results of interrupt handlers or volatile device registers changing.

Do I need to annotate interrupt handlers to mark that they be called at any time? If so, how?

Device registers are accessed through volatile pointers. Is there some annotation that I need to add to suggest to the analyzer what range of values a register can contain, or that they are actually volatile?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't need to do anything special such as annotation to analyze interrupt handlers.  Coverity scans every function in the code, even if it does not see an explicit call to it.  Coverity also understands 'volatile'.

It is possible to inform the analysis about constraints on variable values.  Look in the analysis manual for "modeling".  However, you probably don't need to do that unless you are seeing false positives due to infeasible values.

More generally, if you are concerned about Coverity missing results, I suggest deliberately inserting a few bugs similar to examples in the manual and see if the analysis catches them.  If not, you could try asking about specific examples here or contacting their support team.

(Disclosure: I used to work for Coverity/Synopsys.)